# Wordpress: cutom query by custom metadata (meta field) of taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type "member" with custom taxonomy "member_category". In this taxonomy I have a custom field (as metadata) called "display".

Now I want to query members from the DB and only recieve members who have the taxonomy with the metadata "display" with value of "1".

My attempt is:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'member',
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'member_category',
            'value' => '1',
            'field' => 'term_meta[display]' (????)
            'operator' => 'LIKE'
    )
));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But it's not working.
Any idea? Maybe I should use a SQL query? If so, Which `$wpdb` query should I write?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first fetch the terms having your desired meta value like this:

```
$term_args = array('taxonomy' => 'member_category');
$terms = get_terms( $term_args );
$term_ids = array();
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) )
{
    foreach( $terms as $term ) 
    {
        $val = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'display', true);
        if( $val == '1' ) {
            // push the ID into the array
            $term_ids[] = $term->ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Then passing combined id's on the tax_query as below :

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'member');
$tax_query = array();
if(sizeof($term_ids))
{
    $tax_query = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                         array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'member_category',
                              'field'    => 'ID',
                              'terms'    => $term_ids,
                               'operator' => 'IN',
                               )
                      );
}
if(sizeof($tax_query))
    $args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
```

Comment: @Antika Thank you very much!!
One fix for your answer:
Instead of `$val = get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'display', true);` it should be `$val = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'display', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use SQL queries. If you are querying metadata, you need to use the meta query.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'member',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'display',
        'value' => '1',
    )
));
```

On your args you have everything under tax query which is why it does not work.